# install pm2 globally on redhat 8

Tags: npm, redhat, npm-install, pm2

I have been trying to install pm2 globally on redhat 8 but it is not working. I installed pm2 using

sudo npm i -g pm2

and get

/root/.npm-global/bin/pm2 -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
/root/.npm-global/bin/pm2-dev -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
/root/.npm-global/bin/pm2-docker -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
/root/.npm-global/bin/pm2-runtime -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

- pm2@4.2.2

but when i run

pm2

I get

pm2
-bash: pm2: command not found

pm2 is being installed in a particular folder under the root directory and it can only be access if I go inside that particular directory.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed Node.js runtime using the native package manager prior installing PM2:

```
yum module install nodejs/development
```

Then install PM2:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

Answer (score -1):

it usually does not give problems, but it goes through an installation with SUDO, the solution is:

```
remove pm2
remove npm
clean curl
update curl to NPM 10
install npm @ 10
install pm2 --force
```

---

```
> sudo npm remove pm2
> sudo npm cache clear --force
> sudo apt install
> apt-get dist-upgrade
> sudo apt remove npm
> sudo apt purge npm
> sudo apt remove nodejs
> sudo apt purge nodejs
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
> sudo apt install nodejs
```

(the package nodejs 10.16, npm 6.9)

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g --force
```

if it is due to permissions, use:

```
sudo chmod $USER [path]
```

where [path] = dirs of marker error in LOG.

Comment: RHEL distribution uses YUM and not APT as the package manager, so the commands you mentioned will not work.